# How to post a custom post using facebook javascript api

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Okay i have a website now with an input and button. When the user clicks a button, I want his input to be as a new feed on his facebook account.

I already have added the facebook javascript sdk and the graph api one 
and I created a successful login button and a new feed button sending a standard text which "is this is a text feed".

So how can i post what the user inputs?

The code of posting is

```
function postshare() {
    FB.api(
      "/me/feed",
      "POST",
      {
        "message": "this is a test post"
      },
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
          document.getElementById('poststt').innerHTML = 'post shared succesfully';
        }
      }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a text input on the page with an id, you can reference that input and get its value using `document.getElementById`. So if you had this input

```
<input type="text" id="fb_input" />
```

on your page, you could then do this:

```
function postshare() {
  var message = document.getElementById("fb_input").value;
  FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    {
      "message": message
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
      /* handle the result */
        document.getElementById('poststt').innerHTML = 'post shared succesfully';
      }
    }
  );
}
```